# $_GET('term'] in CJuiAutocomplete Widget

Tags: yii

Where does this 'term' in $_GET['term'] come from. . .

What's the meaning or the content of that 'term'?

here's a sample code:

```
public function actionSuggest() {
    $criteria = new CDbCriteria;
    $criteria->select = array('lastName', 'firstName', 'middleName','idNo','yrLevel','gender');
    $criteria->addSearchCondition('lastName', $_GET['term']);
    $criteria->limit = 10;
    $data = Engineering::model()->findAll($criteria);
    $arr = array();
    foreach ($data as $item) {
        $arr[] = array(
            'label' => $item->lastName.' '.$item->firstName.' '.$item->middleName[0].'.',
            'value' => $item->lastName,
            'lastname' => $item->lastName,
            'firstname' => $item->firstName,
            'middlename' => $item->middleName,
            'idno' => $item->idNo,
            'gender' => $item->gender,
            'yrlevel' => $item->yrLevel,    
        );
    }
    echo CJSON::encode($arr);
}
```

Answer (score 1):

The CJuiAutocomplete widget relies on [jQuery Autocomplete](http://jqueryui.com/demos/autocomplete/) plugin, which sends the contents of textfield as you type in an ajax GET request. Contents of textfield are sent in a GET-parameter `term`. Server-side code should do search by this term and return found records (your code already does that).